# Vue2 property passed to vue3 built web component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have very specific question.

So I am using vue2 as my main project and also I am using my vue3 web components project as an npm library inside that vue2 project (I am basically exposing vue3 built web components).

The question is when I pass an object in property to that vue3 web component from vue2 project and then change some object property (for example I have array as object property and I push new value into it) it does not trigger any watcher or computed (that is watching that property) inside my vue3 web component it simply does not see the change, only way to see the change is to copy the object but that is not ideal. I tried using vue3 to vue3 web component and then it all works like a charm.

Can anyone help with this or at least explain it?

Vue2 project which sees changes when I add deep watcher:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <problem
        :testObject.prop="testObject"
        @testEmit="pushArray"
    />
    {{ testObject }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data()
    {
        return {
            testObject: null,
        };
    },
    created()
    {
        this.testObject = {
            objectArray: [1, 2],
        };
    },
    methods:
    {
        pushArray()
        {
            this.testObject.objectArray.push(5);
        },
    },
    watch: {
       testObject:
       {
           handler(newVal)
           {
               console.log('View watcher triggered', newVal);
           },
           deep: true,
       },
   },
};
</script>
```

Vue3 web component (at export is defined as web component) that does not see change with deep watcher neither computed which should trigger if prop is changed:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Prop Object {{ testObject }}
        <hr>
        Ref Object {{ objectWithArray }}
        <br>
        <button @click="pushArray">
            Push array
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, watch, computed} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent(
{
    props: {
        testObject: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => (null),
        }
    },
    emits: ['testEmit'],
    setup(props, ctx)
    {
        const objectWithArray: any = computed(() => 
        {
            console.log('Computed triggered');
            return props.testObject;
        })

        const pushArray = () =>
        {
            ctx.emit('testEmit');
        }
        

        watch(
            () => props.testObject,
            (newVal) => 
            {
                console.log('Component watcher triggered', newVal);
            },
            {deep: true}
        )

        return {
            pushArray,
            objectWithArray
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This is the normal behaviour of props in Vue 2

They don't "watch" down to deeper levels, by default.

Two solutions in Vue 2 from the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers

#### 1. Explicitly watch particular properties

```js
watch: {
    'some.nested.key'(newValue) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

#### 2. Deep-watch the entire prop

```
export default {
  watch: {
    someObject: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        // Note: `newValue` will be equal to `oldValue` here
        // on nested mutations as long as the object itself
        // hasn't been replaced.
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

See below for @yoduh's excellent point about Vue 3 composition API doing deep watching by default.

Comment: and to address the point where OP said it worked when using a Vue 3 app, that's because watchers are implicitely deep watchers by default in Vue 3 Composition API, whereas you must explicitely opt in to using a deep watcher in Vue 2 Options API.

Comment: As far as I know vue3 watchers are not deep by default there is also deep option for them. But in both cases even tho I put watcher as deep I can't catch changes to that property. I have updated the question!